# Hyperlink vs Anchor

Tags: gwt

When to use HyperLink and when to use Anchor?

When using HyperLink how to handle clicks? 
com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Hyperlink.addClickHandler(ClickHandler) is deprecated 
com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Hyperlink.addClickListener(ClickListener) is deprecated as well.

Doc suggests to use `Anchor#addClickHandler`, but how to use **Anchor**`#addClickHandler` when using **HyperLink**

Does it mean that if I need to handle click I should always use `Anchor` and never use `HyperLink`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Great question, because it is so simple, and yet opens up what might be a whole new area for a lot of GWT programmers.  I've up-voted the question just because it can be a great lead-in for people exploring what GWT can do.

Anchor is a widget for storing and displaying a hyperlink -- essentially the <a> tag.  Really not much more exciting than that.  If you want your page to link to some external site, use anchor.

Links are also used for internal navigation.  Let's say I have a GWT app that requires the user to login, so on my first panel I put a login button.  When the user clicks it, I would display a new panel with widgets to collect the user's information, code to validate it, and then if validated successfully, reconstruct that first panel the user was on.

Buttons are nice, but this is a browser, and I want my user's experience to be more like a web page, not a desktop app, so I want to use links instead of buttons.  Hyperlink does that.  The [documentation for hyperlink](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Hyperlink.html) describes it well:

> A widget that serves as an "internal" hyperlink. That is, it is a link
>   to another state of the running application. When clicked, it will
>   create a new history frame using History.newItem(java.lang.String),
>   but without reloading the page.
>
> Being a true hyperlink, it is also possible for the user to
>   "right-click, open link in new window", which will cause the
>   application to be loaded in a new window at the state specified by the
>   hyperlink.

That second sentence should help clear it up.  The hyperlink is *not* changing the page in a URL sense (the way anchor does), though the URL will reflect the state of the program by displaying the "token" associated with the hyperlink appended to the base URL after a slash.  You define the token.  It would be something descriptive like "login" or "help" or "about".  But this isn't a new page.  There is no additional HTML file you've had to construct to display a help page, for example.  It is the *state* of the current GWT app that is changing.  Even if you "open in a new window" you are just running the same app in a particular state.

It looks like a link, but it is really a widget that manipulates the history frame, which in turn allows you to move the state of your GWT application.  You don't write a click handler for the hyperlink widget, but a value change handler for the history stack.  When you see that the "help" token has been put on the history stack, your handler will execute GWT code to attach to the RootPanel a FlowPanel with embedded HTML text with your help information.   This is perceived by the user as a "new page", which is what he expects when he clicks on a hyperlink.  The URL will be something.html/help.  Now pretend he returns to this URL via the back button, not your hyperlink.  No problem.  You don't care about the hyperlink click.  You only care that, somehow, the history stack changes.  Your value change handler fires again, and does the same thing as before to display the help panel.  The user still enjoys the experience of navigating through web pages, even though you and I know that there is only one web page and that you are attaching and detaching panels to the RootPanel (or whatever scheme you are using to display your GWT panels).

And this leads to a bonus topic.

This bonus is a bit more complicated, but ironically, it could help better understand hyperlinks.  I say more complicated, but really, it helps solidify this notion that a GWT application is made up of a series of states, and that the web page on the screen is just the user's perception of those state changes.  And that is [Activities and Places](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html).  Activities and Places abstracts away this history frame manipulation, handling it in the background once you've set up a mapper with a GWT-provided class designed for this purpose, allowing you to break down your app into a series of activities, and as the user interacts through these activities he is put into different places, and each place has a view.  Moreover, the user can move from place to place using browser controls like the address bar, bookmarks, history, and the backward/forward buttons, giving the user a real web-like experience.  If you really want to get a grip on the conceptual difference between hyperlinks and anchors, you should try to learn this GWT topic.  It can really make you change the way you see your apps, and for the better.

Comment: thanks, if hyperlink is not changing URL, why it affects history? as history in browser is the list of URLs, isn't it? and it still not clear how to handle click on hyperlink in gwt 2.0 or higher

Comment: When the hyperlink is clicked, it automatically puts the token (a short string) you've allocated to that link on the stack, and the URL changes.  Instead of a click handler, you write a value change handler that fires when the history stack changes.  That handler maps changes to the history stack to changes to the state of your program.  Your history stack value change handler would inspect the stack, see the token that is there, and then execute your code to alter the state (and appearance) of your application based on that token. If the user clicks on the back button, the same thing happens.

Comment: Best thing to do is just try it out.  It will all become clear.  Trust me.  And then read about Activities and Places and say, "Oh wow, this handles URLs and histories and everything!"

Comment: By the way, I see where I wasn't clear in saying the URL doesn't change.  The URL does change in that history tokens are appended to the base URL.  But in actual fact, the same GWT program is running attached to the same RootPanel.  The URL changes reflect changes in the state of the GWT program, not a web location in the normal sense .  Does that help?

Comment: thanks Steve very good comment! However I'm marking another answer as correct answer because I think it's more concentrated on my question.

Comment: Hey, if you learned something from my answer, or someone else did, then it's fine by me.

Comment: I understand the difference, but don't see the point of ever using a HyperLink. In fact it sounds to me like using a HyperLink involves jumping through hoops just to get to something that behaves like an Anchor, but with slightly less usefulness (no on click behaviour). The use case makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 5):

`Hyperlink` (or `InlineHyperlink`) is basically no more than a kind of `Anchor` with a `ClickHandler` that calls `History.newItem` and `preventDefault()` the event (so that the link is not actually followed).
Actually, `Hyperlink` won't do that if it thinks (and yes, it's only a guess) you right-clicked or middle-clicked (or ctrl-clicked) on the link (depending on the browser), to open the link in a new window or tab.

If you need any other behavior, then don't use `Hyperlink` and use `Anchor` instead. And if you want to add some behavior to an `Hyperlink`, then use an `Anchor` and mimic what the `Hyperlink` does. And you can reuse the `HyperlinkImpl` to have the right-click/ctrl-click handling (see links below).

But actually, if you need something that looks like a link and do something on click, but does not have a "target URL" (i.e. it shouldn't be right-clicked/ctrl-clicked to open in a new window/tab, or it wouldn't mean anything to do so), then do not use either an `ANchor` or `Hyperlink`, use a `Label` of whatever instead, and make it look like a link (but well, maybe you should use a `Button` and have it look like a button then; Google used to have link-alike buttons –such as the "refresh" link/button in GMail– and changed them to look like buttons when they really aren't links).

See also https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/P7vwRztO6bA/wTshqYs6NM0J and https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/CzOvgVsOfTo/IBNaG631-2QJ

Comment: so cause I don't want to keep history (I actually need to display pop-up dialog on click, like "are you sure?"), i should use Anchor

Comment: but this doesn't correspond with that: "The hyperlink is not changing the page in a URL sense (the way anchor does), though the URL will reflect the state of the program by displaying the "token" associated with the hyperlink appended to the base URL after a slash.". I don't want to change URL. I want to display "are you sure" popup on click. so it seems from the comment below I should use `Hyperlink`, but from your comment I should use `Anchor` :)

Comment: If your "link" doesn't "link" to somewhere ("open in new tab/window" wouldn't make sense), then neither `Hyperlink` nor `Anchor` are appropriate. What @steve-j was trying to say is that with the `Hyperlink`, the link isn't "followed" by the browser (because of the `preventDefault()` done internally), but it'll do a `History.newItem` which will change the URL's hash (effectively "pushing" to the "stack" in the history). With `Anchor`, unless you `preventDefault()` in a `ClickHandler`, the browser will follow the link, and navigate to the given URL.